# Update one record in a table from multiple records of another table. Where column name of one table is field of another one

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

Table 1

[image: Table 1]

Table 2

[image: Table 2]

Need to update table 2 from Table1.Tonnes where Table1.Type matches the column name in table 2. For the row with same date. So far I write an Update query on VBA but it updates the table 2 for only first record in Table 1.

```
aa = recordset.Fields("Type").Value

sql = "UPDATE LossTonnesByUnitAmmonia " _
      & "INNER JOIN TempUnitLossApproval ON(LossTonnesByUnitAmmonia.Date = TempUnitLossApproval.Date) " _
      & "SET LossTonnesByUnitAmmonia." & aa & " = TempUnitLossApproval.Tonnes"

DoCmd.RunSQL sql
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You open the recordset and pick one value from field `Type`, so that's it.

To update more fields, loop the recordset to retrieve all the field names to update, then rebuild/expand your SQL to include these field names.

Comment: Update query changes the Ref column only. Loop can rectify that. But it runs twice and last updated value is from steam. So query will run for all records every time, which will update from the last row everytime.

Comment: Yes, if you run the update inside the loop. Move it outside (after) the loop.